# Implementing custom loss function in Keras for adversial loss?

Tags: machine-learning, theano, keras

I would like to implement a custom loss function in Keras using the prediction made by another network. More specifically, I'd like to use the prediction generated by the discriminator in the loss function for the generator. However, when I try to implement this, I get the following error:

```
    if len(array.shape) == 1:
TypeError: object of type 'TensorVariable' has no len()
```

Is Keras capable of having network predictions in custom loss functions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of dimensions of a tensor use `K.ndim` instead of `K.shape`, e.g.:

```
import keras.backend as K`

def myCustomLoss(x):
    if K.ndim(x) == 3:
        print("is 3")
```

Note that values such as your `array` are just placeholders for data that lies on *some* device, for example your GPU. Therefore things like `len(array)` won't work as the backend would have to fetch these values first and it does not do this automatically because that would be inefficient.